# Implementing WebFilter getting errors: multiples recursive call to localhost

Tags: servlets, servlet-filters

Filtering imposed over url path but when expected URL met in that case i am getting this error.

Error is : Failed to clear temp storage: It was determined that certain files are unsafe for access within a Web application, or that too many calls are being made on file resources. SecurityError

```
Code snap:
@WebFilter(urlPatterns = {"/profile"}, description = "Session Checker Filter")
public class SessionCheckerFilter implements Filter {
    private FilterConfig config = null;
    static int i =0;
    public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException {
        this.config = config;
        config.getServletContext().log("Initializing SessionCheckerFilter");
    }

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res,
                         FilterChain chain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;

        // Check to see if user's session attribute contains an attribute
        // named user_id. If the attribute is not exists redirect
        // user to the login page.
        //
        if (request.getSession().getAttribute("username") == null) {

            System.out.println(++i);
            response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/");
      }
        else 
            response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/profile");

    }
    public void destroy() {
        config.getServletContext().log("Destroying SessionCheckerFilter");
    }
}
```

Comment: @BalusC This problem is little bit different.After authenticating from git outh api i am redirecting user to this URL.In that case i am getting this error. I tried to debug but call is not coming to filter section.

Comment: I recommnend to fix question to remove or clarify/explain "obvious starter's mistakes". The code in its current form has a bug that was answered in the duplicate, but if the filter is in first place not called, then you indeed won't face this bug.

Answer (score 0):

This problem has solved after making two changes .

```
1. My local server running on port 8090 and and in redirect URL i have  defined port is 8080. I have to make it same port.

2. In redirect URL i have defined xx.com other than localhost so in /etc/hosts i have to define xx.com other than localhost.
```